# A Java code about scissor-rock-paper game

Tags: java, switch-statement

I’ve learned Java for 1 month. I have a question about my code.
There is something wrong.If I press 0, the outcomes only has "Computer win" and "Tie" two situation. So as I press 1 and 2, it only comes out two. What's wrong in here ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hm3 {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int Computer=0,Player=0,tie=0,compic=0,pscore=0;tie=0;
    int end = 0;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (end < 3) {
        System.out.print("Enter 0 for Scissors, 1 for Rock, and 2 for Paper : ");
        pscore = scan.nextInt();
        compic = (int)(Math.random()*2);

        switch (pscore){            
        case 0 :
            if (compic == 0){
                System.out.println("Tie");
                tie++;
            }else if (compic == 1){
                System.out.println("Computer Win");
                Computer++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Player Win");
                Player++;
                end++;
            }
            break;
        case 1 :
            if (compic == 0){
                System.out.println("Player Win");
                Player++;
                end++;
            }else if (compic == 1){
                System.out.println("Tie");
                tie++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Computer Win");
                Computer++;
            }break;
        case 2 :
            if (compic == 0){
                System.out.println("Computer Win");
                Computer++;
            }else if (compic == 1){
                System.out.println("Player Win");
                Player++;
                end++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Tie");
                tie++;
            }break;
        default :               
            System.out.println("The wrong value");              
            break;
        }      
  }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The player wins : " + Player);
    System.out.println("The computer wins : " + Computer);
    System.out.println("Tie : " + tie);
 }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at how you calculate `compic`, particularly your multiplier.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: This is a question in the book. I just couldn't solve this one.

Comment: I thought the game was called Rock-Paper-Scissor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I also believe that the problem is with your random number generation. When dealing with integers  I prefer to use this method because there is no rounding or casting involved:

```
Random random = new Random(); //create a random object

random.nextInt(3); //will return a random integer from 0 to 2
```

The number in the parenthesis of the nextInt() method is the range if you want to go from 1 to 3 just alter it to

```
random.nextInt(3) + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you:) I mistake the random 2 is from 0 to 2. Now, I understood what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating random integers from 0 to 1, not from 0 to 2. To fix, do `Math.random()*3`

Answer (score 0):

You've been given the answer, and this isn't code review, but I can't fit this suggestion in a comment.  Rather than three very similar sub-switches of a switch (which is what you effectively have, just with if-else), you can decide this with a single switch by offsetting the computer's choice by a number of bits (2 is all you need to encode three choices, but 4 is more convenient when you must use hexadecimal rather than binary literals) and ORing it with the player's choice to produce a number that encodes both moves.

```
// 0:scissors, 1:rock, 2:paper
private String winner(int player, int computer) {
  switch (player | (computer<<4)) {
    case 0:
    case 0x11:
    case 0x22:
      return "Tie";
    case 0x02:  // computer:scissors, player:paper
    case 0x10:
    case 0x21:
      return "Computer wins";
    case 0x01:
    case 0x12:
    case 0x20:
      return "Player wins";
    default:
      return "error";
  }
}
```