# Scalable solution for Rock-Paper-Scissor

Tags: java, algorithm

Just went through a variant of the game : [Rock-Paper-Scissor-Lizard-Spock](http://www.samkass.com/theories/RPSSL.html)

I have written a Java code for traditional R-P-S problem, but when I tried extending my code for the newer version of the game (R-P-S-L-S)..I felt my code is **terribly** bad. Here is a snippet :

```
 if (player1.equals("ROCK") && 
         player2.equals("SCISSORS")) {
        winner = 1;
    }
    // Paper covers rock...
    else if (player1.equals("PAPER") &&
         player2.equals("ROCK")) {
        winner = 1;
    }
    // Scissors cut paper...
    else if (player1.equals("SCISSORS") &&
         player2.equals("PAPER")) {
        winner = 1;
    }
    else {
        winner = 2;
    }
```

I realized the code cant be extended easily for the newer version - as well as for more than 2 players. This is mainly because of multiple if/else or switch/cases. I need some help **re-designing** my code for achieving the 2 objectives :

1. Further modification as per R-P-C-L-S problem.
2. Support for more than 2 players.

I don't need code, just some guidelines should help.

Thanks !!

**EDIT : Seems like I was wrong in thinking that this game can be played by more than 2 players. I am sorry for this mistake, please ignore the second requirement.**

Comment: I am very much interested in removing if-else blocks and hardcoded data...

Comment: Thanks everyone - just too many good answers !

Comment: Draw the decision table.  Then implement the decision table.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In, Rock-Paper-Scissor games, it is easy to decide if move a wins against move b using their index at a cycle. So you don't have to manually decide in your code the result of every combination as other answers here suggest.

---

For the Rock-Paper-Scissor-Spock-Lizard version:

Let's assign a number to each move (0, 1, 2, 3, 4).

Notice that every move beats two moves:

1. The move previous to it in the cycle (or four cases ahead)
2. The move two cases ahead in the cycle

So let `d = (5 + a - b) % 5`. Then:

1. d = 1 or d = 3 => a wins
2. d = 2 or d = 4 => b wins
3. d = 0 => tie

---

For the Rock-Paper-Scissor version:

let `d = (3 + a - b) % 3`. Then:

1. d = 1 => a wins
2. d = 2 => b wins
3. d = 0 => tie

---

**Generalization** For n >= 3 and n odd:

Let `d = (n + a - b) % n`. Then:

1. If d = 0 => tie
2. If d % 2 = 1 => a wins
3. If d % 2 = 0 => b wins

[image]

Comment: This is by far the most elegant solution here. :)

Comment: Shouldn't it always be `(n + a - b) % 3` since the 3 there stands for "win-loss-draw"?

Answer (score 10):

The nature of Rock-Paper-Scissors is such that you have to explicitly handle the case for every possible combination of states. So the number of cases you have to cover increases exponentially with the number of players, and polynomially (with the order of the polynomial being the number of players) with the number of options.

Having said that, Java's enums are good for this kind of thing.

Here's my stab at it:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

enum Result {
    WIN, LOSE, DRAW;
}

enum Option {

    ROCK(SCISSORS),
    PAPER(ROCK),
    SCISSORS(PAPER);

    private List<Option> beats;

    private Option(Option... beats) {
        this.beats = Arrays.asList(beats);
    }

    Result play(Option other) {
        if beats.contains(other) {
            return Result.WIN;
        } else if other.beats.contains(this) {
            return Result.LOSE;
        } else {
            return Result.DRAW;
        }
    }

}
```

Adding more cases (Lizard and Spock) is consequently relatively simple. Adding more players would be more complicated; among other things, you'd have to determine what the rules of three-player Rock-Paper-Scissors even are, because I have no idea.

Comment: @sch True; I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Though this is the most elegant solution - it won't work.  You cannot reference an Option prior to it being initialized :(.  You need an intermediate 'set' method

Answer (score 1):

i think: 1 beats 2 or 5 loses to the rest.  2 beats 3 or 1 loses to the rest.  3 beats 4 or 2 loses to rest.  4 beats 5 or 3 loses to the rest.  5 beast 1 or 3 loses to the rest.  For 3 players, compare the values of 2 players, then compare the winner vs player 3.

Comment: That's incorrect. With 3 players, each player can win against one of the others. The win-against relation is not associative: A (rock) beats B (scissors) and B (scissors) beats C (paper), but that doesn't mean that A (rock) beats C (paper).

Comment: It is correct.. If A beats B but A does not beat C it is a tie.  Learn about round robin matches.  1 out of 3 times there is not a winner, however there is always a winner 1 vs 1

Comment: if 2 players throw the same, they are only 1 player.  if 3 players throw the same tie

Comment: Let's take my example and your strategy. A beats B, so you compare A with C? A has 1 point for beating B. C has one point for beating A. But B has 0 point, although he beats C. You just forgot to compare B and C.

Answer (score 1):

Design an enum `Choice` (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS), where each enum has a `Set<Choice>` which it wins against.

Have each of your players choose one of the choices.

Iterate through your players, and for each one, iterate over all the other players that are after him in the list of players (for player 0, iterate through players 1, 2, 3, etc; for player 1, iterate through players 2, 3, etc.; ...).

For each match, you have three possibilities:

1. A beats B (the choice of B is in the set of choices that A beats): increment A's score
2. A and B have the same choice: do nothing
3. A doesn't beat B: increment B's score

Answer (score 1):

I suggested a better design [in an answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526222/a-java-code-about-scissor-rock-paper-game/9526418#9526418).  Have a single switch, and switch over a single encoding of every possible combination of moves, and for an encoding use a positional number system with a base that's a power of 2, so that each digit will map directly to a number of bits, and so that bitwise manipulations are intuitive.

Three bits are sufficient for five choices, and although octal would be ideal, the syntax sucks, so use hex.  Each hexadecimal digit then represents one of your five moves, with room to spare.  A byte is large enough two encode the simultaneous moves of two players, an int for eight, a long for sixteen.  It's straightforward.  Follow the link for a code example.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic logic problem.  It is small enough you can do a manual truth table ( or skip ahead to a k-map), minimize and get a solution.

So basically, you need to evaluate first, if it is a draw.  Then, you need to evaluate winning relative to other players.  Doing this without needing to compare against each user can be a confusing task.  Since this only has 5 variables, you can find a minimized solution with a K-map.

You will need to evaluate each user, based on which item they chose with a specific algorithm to determine if they win.  Note that with more than 2 players, there can be more than one winner if two people choose the same thing but both beat a 3rd player.  Or you can consider that a tie, whatever.  I'll assume the former.  You should check also that all players didn't choose the same item.

So I've done the first part of the algorithm for you when the user you are evaluating has chosen "rock".

In code, this would look like:

```
rock=0, paper=0, scissors=0, lizard=0, spock=0, win=0, tie=0
if ( someone chose rock ) rock=1
if ( someone chose paper ) paper=1
if ( someone chose scissors ) scissors=1
if ( someone chose lizard ) lizard=1
if ( someone chose spock ) spock=1

// Check if tie / draw, double check these, but I think I got them all
tie=rock && !paper && spock && lizard || rock && paper && scissors ||  
    rock && paper && lizard || spock && paper && scissors || 
    spock && !rock && paper && lizard || !spock && scissors && lizard && paper

if ( tie ) die()

CheckIfUserWins() {
  if ( user chose rock ) {
    win=rock && !paper && !spock
  if ( user chose paper) {
    // ....  calculate using k-map and fill in

}

return win
```

Notice that `win=rock && !paper && !spock` is exactly what would be expected based on the graphic of what beats what at the link you provided.  So you can go to that graphic and pretty quickly fill in the rest of the equations.

This solution is not dependent on any number of players other than to say "someone chose X".  So it should scale to > 5 players, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**The shortest way:**

```
var n = 5; // Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard-Spock

function calculate(x, y, n) {
  return 1 - ((n + x - y) % n) % 2;
}

function getWinner(p1Gestrure, p2Guesture) {
  if(p1Gestrure === p2Guesture) {
     return - 1; // tie
  }

  return this.calculate(p1Gestrure, p2Guesture); // 0: win for p1. 1: win for p2.
}
```

I've created a cli game, please feel free to take a look there.
https://github.com/julianusti/rpc-es6