# Rock, Paper, Scissors. Determine win/loss/tie using math?

Tags: math, logic, puzzle

So I was writing a rock paper scissors game when I came to writing this function:

`a` is player one's move, `b` is player two's move. All I need to figure out is if player one won, lost, or tied.

```
//rock=0, paper=1, scissors=2
processMove(a, b) {
    if(a == b) ties++;
    else {
             if(a==0 && b==2) wins++;
        else if(a==0 && b==1) losses++;
        else if(a==1 && b==2) losses++;
        else if(a==1 && b==0) wins++;
        else if(a==2 && b==1) wins++;
        else if(a==2 && b==0) losses++;
    }
}
```

My question is: What's the most elegant way this function can be written?

Edit: I'm looking for a one-liner.

Comment: Looking for readable correct code is much better than looking for one-liners.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9553712/1207152

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (a == b) ties++;
else if ((a - b) % 3 == 1) wins++;
else losses++;
```

I need to know exactly which language you are using to turn it into a strictly one-liner...

For JavaScript (or other languages with strange Modulus) use:

```
if (a == b) ties++;
else if ((a - b + 3) % 3 == 1) wins++;
else losses++;
```

Comment: rock vs scissors doesn't work: `(0 - 2 % 3) = -2`. Using `javascript`

Comment: Looks like it's missing a pair of parenthesis: ((a-b) % 3 == 1). In C operators modulo is higher in order of operations than subtraction.

Comment: It's not a strange modulus its: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder#description > While in most languages, `%` is a **remainder** operator, in some (e.g. Python, Perl) it is a **modulo** operator. For two values of the same sign, the two are equivalent, but when the operands are of different signs, the **modulo** result always has the same sign as the *divisor*, while the **remainder** has the same sign as the *dividend*, which can make them differ by one unit of the divisor.

Comment: For languages where `%` is a remainder operator, use `((n % d) + d) % d` or in this case `(((a - b) % 3) + 3) % 3`

Answer (score 8):

A 3x3 matrix would be "more elegant", I suppose.

```
char result = "TWLLTWWLT".charAt(a * 3 + b);
```

(Edited: Forgot that `a` and `b` were already zero-origin.)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use the terniary operator like this -

```
if (b==0) a==1? wins++ : loss++;

if (b==1) a==1? loss++ : wins++;

if (b==2) a==1? loss++ : wins++;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple mathematical formula to get the result and then compare with `if` like this:

```
var moves = {
  'rock': 0, 
  'paper': 1,
  'scissors': 2
};
var result = {
  'wins': 0,
  'losses': 0,
  'ties': 0
};
var processMove = function (a, b) {
  var processResult = (3 + b - a) % 3;
  if (!processResult) {
    ++result['ties'];
  } else if(1 == processResult) {
    ++result['losses'];
  } else {
    ++result['wins'];
  }
  return result;
};
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7a6RF/)

---

One line `processMove` function without return:

```
var processMove = function (a, b) {
  ((3 + b - a) % 3) ? 1 == ((3 + b - a) % 3) ? ++result.losses : ++result.wins : ++result.ties;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

how do you do it in java?

result = (comp - x ) % 3 ;

```
System.out.println (result);
 if (result == 0 )// if the game is tie
 {
     System.out.println ("A Tie!") ;
 }

 else if (result == 1 || result == 2 )
 {
    //System.out.println (user + " " +   "beats" + " " + computer_choice + " you win" );
     System.out.println ("comp win");
 }

 else
 {
     System.out.println ("you win");
    //System.out.println (computer_choice  + " " +  "beats" + " " + user + "you lose");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will come in handy someone (JavaScript):

```
if (a == b) ties++;
else if ((a - b) == 1 || (b - a) == 2) losses++;
else wins++;
```

PHP:

```
function check($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return "Tie";
    }
    if (($a - $b) == 1 || ($b - $a) == 2) {
        return "You Lose";
    } else 
        return "You Win";
}
```