# Rock Paper Scissors Lizard and Spock. WIns Counter not working

Tags: python, counter

I am stuck on trying to get it to display the number of wins for both the computer and player. I tried using `while` statements but they never seemed to work so I have `if` statements that don't allow me to go past 1. Need help understanding what needs to be changed on lines 57, 58, 66 and 69.

```
selection = {"0" : "Rock", "1" : "Paper", "2" : "Scissors", "3" : "Lizard", "4" : "Spock"}

def RPSLS():

 Player = random.randrange(5)
 Computer = random.randrange(5)

 print "\n"
 def Selection(Player):
     if Player == 0:
         Player = selection["0"]
     elif Player == 1:
         Player = selection["1"]
     elif Player == 2:
         Player = selection["2"]
     elif Player == 3:
         Player = selection["3"]
     else:
         Player = selection["4"]
     print "Player chooses", Player
     return Player

 Selection(Player)

 def Selection(Computer):
     if Computer == 0:
         Computer = selection["0"]
     elif Computer == 1:
         Computer = selection["1"]
     elif Computer == 2:
         Computer = selection["2"]
     elif Computer == 3:
         Computer = selection["3"]
     else:
         Computer = selection["4"]
     print "Computer chooses", Computer
     return Computer

 Selection(Computer)

 def Wins():
     Difference = (Player - Computer) % 5
     Playerwins =+ 0
     Computerwins =+ 0

     if Difference == 0:
             print "Player and Computer tie!"
     elif Difference <= 2:
             Playerwins =+ 1
             print "Player Wins!"
     else:
             Computerwins =+ 1
             print "Computer Wins!"

     print "\n"
     print "Player Wins:", Playerwins
     print "Computer Wins:", Computerwins
     return Wins
 Wins()

Loop = 0

while Loop != 10:
 RPSLS()
 Loop += 1

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Just a suggestion - I would replace `selection` with a `list`. A `dict` isn't useful here since the keys are just sequential integers (casted to strings).

Comment: You want `+=` not `=+` in the `Wins` function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues with your code in terms of scope, syntax, naming conventions, etc. I recommend reading a tutorial on Python [**best practices**](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/). However, without doing a complete rewrite, here are minimum number of changes I needed to make to get your code to work.

```
import random

selection = {0 : "Rock", 1 : "Paper", 2 : "Scissors", 3 : "Lizard", 4 : "Spock"}

Playerwins = 0
Computerwins = 0

def RPSLS():
    global Playerwins, Computerwins

    Player = random.randrange(5)
    Computer = random.randrange(5)

    print "Player chooses", selection[Player]
    print "Computer chooses", selection[Computer]

    Difference = (Player - Computer) % 5

    if Difference == 0:
        print "Player and Computer tie!"
    elif Difference <= 2:
        Playerwins += 1
        print "Player Wins!"
    else:
        Computerwins += 1
        print "Computer Wins!"

    print "Player Wins:", Playerwins
    print "Computer Wins:", Computerwins
    print "\n"

Loop = 0

while Loop != 10:
    RPSLS()
    Loop += 1

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Also, I don't think your Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock rules are correct by the [**usual rules**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons). According to your rules Spock beats Lizard. Check out this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553058/scalable-solution-for-rock-paper-scissor).