# Trying to code a Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Alright so I need to create the code needed to create a Rock Paper Scissors type game with an example output looking something like this:

```
Rock­Paper­Scissors ­ pick your weapon[R,P,S]:: R
player had rock
computer had paper
!Computer wins <<Paper Covers Rock>>!
Do you want to play again? y

Rock­Paper­Scissors ­ pick your weapon[R,P,S]:: R
player had rock
computer had scissors
!Player wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!
Do you want to play again? y

Rock­Paper­Scissors ­ pick your weapon[R,P,S]:: R
player had rock
computer had rock
!Draw Game!
Do you want to play again? n
```

So I'm basically completely stumped and I'm not really sure what to do from here, the code needs to be able to let the user choose R, P, or S and let the computer determine a random instance of such. I'm not asking you guys to do the whole thing for me (but feel free to) but just some direction/help would be greatly appreciated, so here is what I have so far:

RockPaperScissors Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
    private String playChoice;
    private String compChoice;

    public RockPaperScissors
    {
        playChoice=null; //same as playChoice="";
        compChoice=null;
    }
    //loaded constructor 
    public RockPaperScissors(String player)
    {
        //add code here to call the setPlayers method
    }
    //set playChoice based on player choice and compChoice based on random number
    public void setPlayers (String player)
    {
        //switch case
        //R-player="rock"
        //P-player="paper"
        //S-player="scissors"

        //int num=random number 0 1 or 2
        //switch case
        //0-computer="rock"
        //1-computer="paper"
        //2-computer="scissors"
    }
    //using logic and possible player and computer choices, determine a winner and return the string that informs the player who won
    public String determineWinner()
    {
        String winner="";
        //if playChoice is the same as compChoice no winner (draw)
        //else-if-else if statements to compare playChoice and compChoice to find the winner
        return winner;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";
        output=output + "player had " + playChoice+"\n;
        output+="computer had "+ compChoice;
        return output;
    }
}
```

And the runner class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RPSRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        weapon[R,P,S]:: ");
        RockPaperScissors(keyboard.next());
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response;
        do{
            System.out.print("Rock­Paper­Scissors ­ pick your
            RockPaperScissors test = new
            System.out.println(test); //uses toString method
            System.out.println(test.determineWinner()+"\n");
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
            response = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        }while(response=='Y'||response=='y');
    }
}
```

Thanks for any and all help.

As requested here is the entire assignment:

LAB DESCRIPTION :   Program a simple game of Rock, Paper, Scissors. Generate a random choice

for the computer player.  Next, the person player will make a choice.  Finally, you take the two choices

and see which one of the players is the winner.  You will need to use Random numbers.

Help for Random numbers can be found here ( https://goo.gl/YgH1ld )

Comment: Why not use characters, and run the whole game in the runner? You can use `keyboard.next().charAt(0)` for R, P, or S, and you can also do `keyboard.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0)` for your Y/N;

Comment: This post might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553058/scalable-solution-for-rock-paper-scissor?rq=1

Comment: Well this is an assignment for class, so it must be done similar to what I have posted, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: @jbinx the code as posted is broken. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post the assignment exactly actually. It isn't really proper to ask for full solutions if this is homework. You should actively discourage people from providing full solutions as that will rob you of the experiential learning and make future assignments even harder.

Comment: Wow. The lab has syntax errors. That's very bad. I'll attempt to correct those as well.

Comment: Did this come from a PDF? Copy/paste is pretty hit and miss from PDF.

Comment: I trimmed off the assignment code as it didn't format nicely. Thank you for sharing it though.

Comment: @jbinx does my answer have a sensible version of the runner?  Do you want to start posing questions as comments on that answer and we can work iteratively toward solving this together?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to:

1. Print a prompt asking to choose a weapon (DONE)
2. Take an input for the weapon
3. Pick a random weapon for the computer player
4. Determine who wins
5. Print a prompt asking to play again (DONE)
6. Take an input to play again (DONE)
7. Loop back to step 1 (DONE)

So you need to implement 2-4.

The main problem is the brokenness of the runner.  I'm posting a corrected version below which implements 2 (but doesn't validate that it's R, P, or S):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RPSRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RockPaperScissors(keyboard.next());
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response;
        do{
            System.out.print("Rock­Paper­Scissors ­ pick your weapon[R,P,S]:: ");
            String player = keyboard.next();
            RockPaperScissors test = new RockPaperScissors(player);
            System.out.println(test); //uses toString method
            System.out.println(test.determineWinner()+"\n");
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
            response = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        }while(response=='Y'||response=='y');
    }
}
```

Starting with the lab pieces.  What do you think is needed here?

```
    public RockPaperScissors(String player)
    {
        //add code here to call the setPlayers method
    }
```