# How to add infinite variations of rock paper scissor without typing full comparison

Tags: javascript

I want to add an infinite amount of options to choose from when playing the rock paper scissor game (steen, papier, schaar === rock, paper, scissor). I've looked on Stackoverflow and found some solutions, but i can't figure out how to implement it in my own code.

Here is the link of the solution without implementing it in my own code:

[Scalable solution for Rock-Paper-Scissor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553058/scalable-solution-for-rock-paper-scissor)

```
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
let computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
let scoreMessage = document.getElementById("score-message");
const schaar_div = document.getElementById("schaar");
const steen_div = document.getElementById("steen");
const papier_div = document.getElementById("papier");

// Computer choice
function getRandomChoise() {
const choises = ["schaar", "steen", "papier"];
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choises.length);
return choises[randomNumber];
}

function win() {
userScore++;
userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
scoreMessage.innerHTML = "<span style='color: green;'>You Won!</span>";
}

function lose() {
computerScore++;
computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
scoreMessage.innerHTML = "<span style='color: red;'>You Lost!</span>"
}

function draw() {
scoreMessage.innerHTML = "It's a Draw!"

}


function Game(userChoise) {
const computerChoise = getRandomChoise();
if (userChoise + computerChoise === "steenschaar") {
    win();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "papiersteen") {
    win();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "schaarpapier") {
    win();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "steenpapier") {
    lose();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "papierschaar") {
    lose();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "schaarsteen") {
    lose();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "schaarschaar") {
    draw();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "steensteen") {
    draw();
} else if (userChoise + computerChoise === "papierpapier") {
    draw();
}


}

function main() {
schaar_div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    Game("schaar");
})

steen_div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    Game("steen");
})

papier_div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    Game("papier");
})
}

main();
```

I want to be able to add an infinite amount of options to the game (lizzard, spock, ...) without writing the else if declarations over and over again.

Comment: Look for documentation on `switch` or maybe even `foreach`

Answer (score 2):

The article you linked gives you this logical approach to rock paper scissors:

> Generalization For n >= 3 and n odd:
>
> Let d = (n + a - b) % n. Then:
>
> If d = 0 => tie
>
> If d % 2 = 1 => a wins
>
> If d % 2 = 0 => b wins

You could implement this like so:

```js
// convert names to numbers
const options = {
  rock: 0,
  paper: 1,
  scissors: 2
}

// length of object
const length = Object.keys(options).length

// user input
const user = options[prompt().toLowerCase()]

// randomly generate input for opponent
const comp = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(length));

// debug
console.log(user, comp)

// conditions
const win = () => console.log('win')
const lose = () => console.log('lose')
const tie = () => console.log('tie')

// calculate output
const d = (length + user - comp) % length

// d = 0 -> tie
// d % 2 = 1 -> win
// d % 2 = 0 -> lose
d ? d % 2 ? win() : lose() : tie()
```

This approach is automatically scalable; you can add two more entries into the object and the code will automatically accommodate for it. I extracted the code into a function, and made it more of a game:

```js
// convert names to numbers
const options = {
  rock: 0,
  paper: 1,
  scissors: 2,
  spock: 3,
  lizard: 4
}

const condition = (input, comp, condition) => {
  switch (condition) {
    case 'win':
      order = [input, comp]
      break
    case 'lose':
      order = [comp, input]
      break
    case 'tie':
      order = [input]
      break
  }
  
  console.log(`You chose ${input}, and the opponent chose ${comp},`)

  order.length > 1
    ? console.log(`${order[0]} beats ${order[1]}.`)
    : console.log(`${order[0]} cannot beat iself.`)
    
  console.log(`You ${condition}.`)
  
}


const play = (input, options) => {
  input = options[input.toLowerCase()]

  var length = Object.keys(options).length
  var comp = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(length))
  var d = (length + input - comp) % length
  
  input = Object.keys(options)[input]
  comp = Object.keys(options)[comp]
  
  condition(input, comp, d ? d % 2 ? 'win' : 'lose' : 'tie')
}


const input = prompt()
play(input, options)
```

Comment: This only works if every options wins over the next and looses over the previous one ...

Comment: Which is exactly how the logic works in rock paper scissors, along with variants. Although, it is every other, not the next or previous.

Answer (score 0):

You could express the repationships between two possible options as a tree:

```
  const winsOver = {
    schaar: ["papier"],
    steen: ["schaar"],
    papier: ["steen"],
 };
```

Now your comparison gets as easy as:

```
 if(userChoice === computerChoice) {
   draw();
 } else if(winsOver[userChoice].includes(computerChoice)) {
   win();
 } else lose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same idea as Jonas Wilms, but it's make me more time to elaborate

```js
const win3 = { Rock:     { e: [ 'Scissors' ], m: [ 'Rock crushes Scissors'] }
,              Paper:    { e: [ 'Rock' ],     m: ['Paper cover Rock']       }
,              Scissors: { e: [ 'Paper'],     m: ['Scissors cuts Paper']    }
            }

const win5 = { Rock:     { e: [ 'Scissors', 'Lizard'   ], m: [ 'Rock crushes Scissors', 'Rock crushes Lizard'         ] }
,              Paper:    { e: [ 'Rock'    , 'Spock'    ], m: [ 'Paper cover Rock',      'Paper disproves Spock'       ] }
,              Scissors: { e: [ 'Paper'   , 'Lizard'   ], m: [ 'Scissors cuts Paper',   'Scissors decapitates Lizard' ] }
,              Lizard:   { e: [ 'Paper'   , 'Spock'    ], m: [ 'Lizard eats Paper',     'Lizard poisons Spock'        ] }
,              Spock:    { e: [ 'Rock'    , 'Scissors' ], m: [ 'Spock vaporizes Rock',  'Spock smashes Scissors'      ] }
            }


let play          = win3  // win5 .. win1000...
,   userScore     = 0
,   computerScore = 0
;
function game ( userChoice, computerChoice )
{
  if (userChoice == computerChoice )
  {
    console.log(' same values , no one score')
    return
  }
  if (play[userChoice].includes(computerChoice) )
  {
    userScore++
    let n = play[userChoice].e.findIndex(e=>e===computerChoice )
    console.log( play[userChoice].m[n] )
  }
  else
  {
    computerScore++
    let n = play[computerChoice].e.findIndex(e=>e===userChoice )
    console.log( play[computerChoice].m[n] )
  }
}
```